# Failed retrieveing data fault string="Java.Lang.Stackoverflow error : null

Tags: spring, hibernate, jakarta-ee, apache-flex, flex3

Failed retrieveing data fault string="Java.Lang.Stackoverflow error : null in flex with Java & hibernate while we are trying create or save ticket notes.we are facing this issue?
i would appreciate if have tips or resolution for this issue?

Comment: i think if the attachment size is more then are we facing this issue

Comment: Add some code related to the issue, and show complete stacktrace of exception.